# Why is Comparator Output Offset by -5V with a Unipolar Supply?

Tags: comparator

This circuit works as desired. It switches at 10mV.

But the output is offset by -5V. That is, LOW = -5V and HIGH = 0V, which isn't desired.

**How to make the outputs LOW = 0V and HIGH = 5V?**

[image]

Link to simulation on Falstad/Lush in comment, below:

Comment: The link does not work (at least for me).

Comment: @KevinWhite Stack doesn't allow short urls in questions. This works: http://tinyurl.com/r8nxhtm

Comment: Strange that output isn't -5V to 5V, which would be dead easy to convert to your requirement with 2 resistors.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the symbol for the comparator does not have any power supply pins.

It is presumably being impicitly powered by +5V and -5V.

Look for another comparator variant in your simulator library that allows you set the power supplies.

Comment: Prolly correct! Unfortunately, Lush doesn't have a comparator with power-supply control.